# NSNumber with IF statement issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnumber

I am loading data from a server but I have an issue that the value that I am returning is zero(0) while I can't go inside if. Please where would be the problem?

```
-(void)method1
{
     NSNumber *value = [data objectForKey:@"samount"];
     NSLog(@"number is -%@-", value); //number is -0-
     if (value == 0)
     {
          NSLog(@" OK :) ");
     }
     else 
     {
          NSLog(@"  Bad :( ");
     }
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as an **if loop**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `isEqual:`

```
if ([value isEqual:@(0)])
```

That will also evaluate correctly in case `value` is `nil` (where `==` comparison with `floatValue` or similar methods would fail)

Comment: I have tried your code but it didn't work, it pass the if method.

Comment: Are you sure that you have an `NSNumber` here? Try to `NSLog(@"%@", [value class])`

Comment: value class is __NSCFString

Comment: Then you got an `NSString` and that is the problem. You have to convert it to an `NSNumber` before assignment.

Comment: I will try to change the value type and write here. Thank you.

Comment: You could convert your string to an `int` and box it into an `NSNumber` like this: `@([[data objectForKey:@"samount"] intValue])`

Answer (score 3):

`value` is an object, and more precisely a `NSString` object (as per your comments in Alladinian's answer), but you are checking its address. You can convert your string to `NSNumber` with `NSNumberFormatter` and then check its value or rely on NSString's built-in methods: `integerValue`, `floatValue`, etc.

Assuming `value` is a `NSNumber`/`NSString`:

```
if ([value integerValue] == 0)
```

See [Getting Numeric Values](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW35) in `NSString` documentation and [Accessing Numeric Values](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000178-DontLinkElementID_12) in the `NSNumber` documentation and pick the method that best suits your data type.

Comment: You're right, but comparing floats with `==` is not the best idea.

Comment: @Alladinian It would. Whether it is wrong or not, it is more of a semantic issue.

Comment: @albertamg It works. Will it effect if the value is `nil` or not? I am confused

Comment: @LuaiKalkatawi if the value is `nil` it will go into the `if` branch.

Comment: @FreeNickname you are right about the float comparison, but I did not want to complicate things. I don't even know the data type of `samount`. I could have assumed that `samount` was an integer and have written `intValue` instead.

Comment: I will try to change the value type and write here. Thank you.

Comment: albertamg has a good point here. Also it is good to keep monetary amounts in some kind of integers (number of cents for example). But this is off-topic here.